# jQuery get request returns gmaps4rails, displays nothing

Tags: jquery, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-3.2, partial, gmaps4rails

Simple, I have a jquery-ui slider just above my gmap(Using gmaps4rails).

When I slide it, I change the value from 2,4,6 and so on. This triggers the following jQuery function,

```
$.get('/update_local_grid ,function(data){

                    $("#map-grid").html(data);               


 });
```

In the controller,

```
def update_local_grid

  @json = self.set_json

  render :partial => "maps"

end
```

View,

```
<div id="map-grid"> 

  <%= render "maps" %>

</div>
```

_maps.html.erb

```
<%= gmaps(:map_options => { :container_class => "map_container_renamed" },
                            :markers => {:data => @json,
                            :options => {:auto_adjust => true,
                            :center_on_user => true,
                            :auto_zoom => true,
                            :zoom => 50}}) %>

<%= yield :scripts %>
```

**When I give an HTML request, the map shows up. But, when I slide the jquery-ui slider and give a javascript request, the partial that Im rendering is showing blank on the firebug console.**

I know apneadiving will help me. But others too, save my week.